# Declare Weak in response completion handler

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm learning about weak vs strong and still don't fully grasp it. How can I declare weak response in the following function so I don't have a retained cycle?

```
AF.request(url, method: .get).validate().responseData { [weak self] response in
    guard let data = response.data else {
        completionHandler(.failure(.apiFailed))
        return
    }

    do {
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(.success(decodedData))
        }
    } catch {
        completionHandler(.failure(.corruptedData))
        return
    }
}
```

Right now I have an xcode warning saying:

`Variable 'self' was written to, but never read`

[image]

How can I read it using weak?

Comment: As an aside, you can use `responseDecodable` for automatic decoding using Alamofire.

Comment: Amazing! I didn't know that one! @JonShier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A retain cycle can only happen when an object ends up owning itself through a series of `strong` relationships, usually through one or more objects in a chain. For instance, if an object `A` has an owning relationship to an object `B`, and object `B` has an owning relationship to object `A`, then `A` ends up with an owning relationship to itself, which can prevent it from being deallocated. Breaking this cycle requires one of these objects to change its ownership to a non-owning relationship (`weak`, or `unowned`). (This can also happen if `A` stores a `strong` reference directly to itself, or if the chain goes `A -> B -> C -> D -> A`, or any number of other configurations.)

In the context of callbacks like this, the risk you run into with retain cycles is that if object `A` stores a closure which has a `strong` (the implicit default) reference to `A` somewhere inside of it, it cyclicly refers to itself.

**However:** this only happens if the closure actually has a reason to maintain a `strong` reference to `A` in the first place. Your closure, for instance, never refers to `self` inside of it, so would have no reason to maintain a reference to `self`, `strong` or otherwise. Closures only maintain references (or "close over", hence "closure") to the things used inside of them — and `self` is not.

Hence the warning: you are never "reading" (i.e. accessing) `self` anywhere inside of the closure, so the `[weak self]` is unnecessary altogether.